# Sort HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I had created html table dynamically like this. Now I want to sort the table based on Name while clicking the Name Header in client side. How can I achieve this?

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<table border='1' id='tblCustomers'>");

        sb.Append("<tr>");

        sb.Append("<th>");
        sb.Append("Name");
        sb.Append("</th>");

        sb.Append("<th>"); 
        sb.Append("City");
        sb.Append("</th>");          


        sb.Append("</tr>");
        for(int i=0; i< dtcustomers.count;i++)
        {
           sb.Append("<tr>");

           sb.Append("<td>");
           sb.Append(dtcustomers.Rows[i]["Name"]);
           sb.Append("</td>");

           sb.Append("<td>");
           sb.Append(dtcustomers.Rows[i]["City"]);
           sb.Append("</td>");

           sb.Append("</tr>");
        }

         sb.Append("</table>");
         this.mydiv.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: it will be much easier to sort the array udtcustomers.Rows instead of the table

Comment: have a look at datatables.net

Comment: it can be done using javascript or a jquery plugin on the client side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery and want this done Client Side, you can try [this handy plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).

Comment: I am using jquery 1.8.2. Is it support table sort? <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> How can I add tablesorter.js file. could you please post link for that?

Comment: Does this solution support paged data? In other words, if there are 100 possible records and I have a page size of 10, will the plug in allow for the source data to be requeried to get the first 10 records by the new sort criterion?

Answer (score 0):

This is also really useful: https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

It gives you a js library to install and from there all you have to do is link it to your project with `<script src="sorttable.js"></script>` and add a class to your table. Really easy.

Comment: Does this solution support paged data? In other words, if there are 100 possible records and I have a page size of 10, will the plug in allow for the source data to be requeried to get the first 10 records by the new sort criterion?